# Bootstrap Subtheme undefined variable error for custom node type template

Tags: 7, theming, bootstrap-theme

I am using the [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme, I created a subtheme and duplicated `page.tpl.php` into my subtheme: `/subtheme/templates/system/page.tpl.php`

I then duplicated `page.tpl.php` and renamed to `node--[mytype].tpl.php`. The template is registering but it is filled with "undefined variable" errors. The errors don't happen `/subtheme/templates/system/page.tpl.php`  but happen when I add `node--[mytype].tpl.php` despite having the same code.

I've tried putting in `node--[mytype].tpl.php` in different directories including subtheme root and `/templates/` but errors persists.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating node.tpl.php (instead of page.tpl.php) and putting it in /subtheme/templates/node/node--[type].tpl.php fixed my undefined variable error.